# plotting heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am learning to program in R and appreciate any help. I would like to match column value to reference and produce heatmap where the fill is the total frequency value as given below. I also would like to maintain order of the x value given by "from.aa"

**Reference**

```
Y_aa <- ("ILVFMCAGPTSYWQNHEDKR*X")
yaxis_aa <-strsplit(Y_aa,"")[[1]]
```

**Dataset**

```
> c_1
    from.aa to.aa total.freq
1         R     S  0.7368421
2         W     *  0.7368421
3         G     G  0.7368421
4         E     D  0.7368421
5         S     G  0.7368421
6         P     Q  0.7368421
7         P     Q  0.7368421
8         G     G  0.7368421
9         P     T  0.7368421
10        P     T  0.7368421
11        S     S  0.7368421
12        A     A  0.7368421
13        A     P  0.7368421
14        A     P  0.7368421
15        Q     *  0.7368421
16        Q     *  0.7368421
17        V     V  0.7368421
18        S     E  0.7368421
19        S     E  0.7368421
20        S     E  0.7368421
21        L     L  0.7368421
22        L     L  0.7368421
23        R     L  0.7368421
24        R     L  0.7368421
```

The from.aa values are positional values and hence the order must remain the same as given in the dataset.

Currently, I used ggplot to do the heatmap but the order of x-axis was not preserved.

```
head(c_melt)
  from.aa to.aa   variable     value
1       R     S total.freq 0.7368421
2       W     * total.freq 0.7368421
3       G     G total.freq 0.7368421
4       E     D total.freq 0.7368421
5       S     G total.freq 0.7368421
6       P     Q total.freq 0.7368421
ggplot(data = c_melt, aes(x=from.aa, y=to_aa, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

So my question is; is it possible to do a heatmap of total.freq value as fill and where the order of x-axis ("from.aa") can be preserved while the y axis value i.e. "to.aa" be mapped to reference values i.e. "yaxis_aa"

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I used ggplot2 to make the heatmap but was unable to maintain the order as desired i.e. order given by "from.aa" on the x-axis; ggplot(data = c_melt, aes(x=from.aa, y=yaxis_aa, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile()      So is there a way to plot with a reference y axis whilst maintaining the order of the x axis.

Comment: Do you try to convert `from.aa` in a factor and specify the levels of the factor in the desired order ? See an help [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/7433_4537ea5073dc4162950abb715f513469.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get some plot but it still missing two important data elements.

Before that, I added one more column to my datasets that is for from.aa data since its position, I created a column 0:length(c_l$from.aa) and used this as my x-axis. In this dataset, the length is 123.

The other thing I used was

```
c_melt=melt(c_1, id.var = c('pos.aa','from_aa', 'to_aa'))
```

However in the heatmap all values of from.aa and to.aa are not show on heatmap

```
ggplot(data = c_melt, aes(x=pos.aa, y=to.aa, fill=value, color=value)) + 
       geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
       geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2))) +
       scale_fill_gradient(low = "light blue", high = "red") +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0:123), labels=factor(0:123)) +
    ylab("aa Change") +
    xlab("Reference aa by position") +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 2),
        plot.title = element_text(size=12),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
    labs(fill = "value")
```

The heatmap is as follows;

[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1J5I.png)

Any suggestion to improve this heatmap will be very helpful. Also I intend to add secondary label to the x-axis with from.aa values